# Dynamic table layout - rows and data changes on each run

Tags: android, layout

In my android application I will show user to enter some input values (in main layout) and when presses a button it fetches data from a website(uses AsyncTask). And after fetching i want to display output in a separate layout.

Layout should be like this:

```
----------------------------
Status: Success
----------------------------
Details are as follows:
----------------------------
Name of cust.        ABCDEFG
Age                       16
Total days               365
Present                  300
Absent                    65
Salary                 10000
etc..
----------------------------
           BACK
----------------------------
```

For first two rows, a LinearLayout with TextViews in it is in my mind. For last button "BACK", it is going to be displayed in a LinearLayout. For details i am going to use TableLayout. But this details section is dynamic. that is number of rows varies. When user presses "BACK" button he can do a new fetching and details of new fetch will again be displayed.

I am going to use ScrollView for details section to allow users to view contents if there is larger rows. So I can create the layout dynamically by using code. But I donot know what to do when user presses BACK button and again fetches. Will this already created design stays in memory ? Or any better approach or suggestions ? Also the text in first column of the details section may contain larger texts. So what to do there?

Comment: If user presses "Back" button he goes to previous Activity. If you start async task at onCreate he will see featched data, but if you start task at onResume all data will be refreshed. Can you explain logic of you app. in general? may be with some diagrams

Comment: thanku. When user presses back button main layout is displayed. AsyncTask is executed when "Submit" button on main layout is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advice against the use of tableview, have had several problems with it in the past, and in your case a relative layout will do just as well. Example below highlights what you would need for every row of your details.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Regarding larger test, assuming the text is long, and not just large font size, you can add

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

to you TextView to make it cut the text if its getting to long, and end it with "...". For that to work you need to tell the first textView1 in the example above to:

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
```

and if you dont want the text cut, just remove the android:ellipsize line.

Comment: Lett me know if you want to use this approach and need any more help with it :) Always happy to help and learn a bit on the way :)

Comment: thanku. Maximum rows for details section can be 12. There is no more. But minimum can be 5. So on each fetching, number of rows will be between 5 and 12. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: I would suggest a for loop that inflates a xml containing the above example, and then adds that to a linear layout for each "row" that you want in your details section.

Comment: thanku. So each row is a relative layout containing 2 TextViews, correct ?

Comment: Jupp, that would work well i think. Put the example above in a rox.xml and the add a LinearLayout to you main xml file that you call android:id="@+id/details", and the from code you can loop over the details items and for each of the you can use:
RelativeLayout row = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.row, your linear layout goes here)
to inflate the row.xml.

Comment: And then you can find the textviews by TextView tv1 = row.findById(R.id.textview1);